# Trouble linking Windows API function (ExitProcess) in NASM assembly code with GCC on MinGW

Tags: assembly, gcc, nasm

I am attempting to write a simple assembly program in NASM on Windows that includes a loop and calls the ExitProcess function from the Windows API. I've successfully assembled the code using NASM, but when I try to link it with GCC on MinGW, I encounter an "undefined reference" error for ExitProcess@4.

Here's my assembly code (file.asm):

```
section .data
    i dd 0

section .text
    global _start

    extern ExitProcess@4   ; Import ExitProcess function from kernel32.dll

_start:
    mov ecx, 1000000       ; set loop counter

    ; loop start
loop_start:
    mov eax, [i]           ; load i into eax
    ; your code inside the loop (e.g., b = i) goes here

    add eax, 1             ; increment eax
    mov [i], eax           ; store the result back to i

    cmp eax, ecx           ; compare i with loop counter
    jl loop_start          ; jump to loop_start if i < ecx

    ; your code after the loop (e.g., input(time() - a)) goes here

    ; exit the program
    push 0                  ; exit code 0
    call ExitProcess@4      ; call ExitProcess function

    ; It's good practice to have a ret instruction, even though it will not be reached
    ret
```

I'm using the following commands to assemble and link:

```
nasm -f win32 file.asm -o file.obj
gcc file.obj -o file.exe -m32 -nostartfiles -lkernel32 -luser32
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
file.obj:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `ExitProcess@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried various combinations of libraries (-lkernel32, -luser32, etc.), but the issue persists. How can I properly link the ExitProcess function with GCC on MinGW? Is there something I'm missing in the linking process?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use `_ExitProcess@4` with a leading underscore.

Comment: I might amend Jester's response to say: *For 32bit code, use _ExitProcess@4 with a leading underscore.*

Comment: @Jester nasm -f win32 file.asm -o file.obj
file.asm:27: error: symbol `_ExitProcess@4' not defined

Comment: You probably forgot to change the `extern` too.

Comment: That worked thanks but the exe file didn't do anything. To be honest i just want print the "a" letter 10000000000000 times and then get the time taken. Can you help me?